# Override Visual Studio (2013) default Build Solution (F6) to use Incredibuild instead?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, incredibuild

I'm currently using the Free version of the Incredibuild for Visual Studio 2013 (https://www.incredibuild.com/accelerate-visual-studio-cc-builds.html).

Is there a way we can override VS's "Build Solution" button (F6) to use the Incredibuild "Build Solution" button (Ctrl + Alt + 8) instead at all?

Comment: I never used Incredibuild, but try `Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard`. Your plugin should be there, along with standard keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @Drop you can simply override the default keyboard shortcuts to use the Incredibuild.BuildSolution for F6 via:

```
Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard
```